# django dynamic forms with widgets

Tags: django, forms, dynamic, widget

I am using the tutorial at http://proteus-tech.com/blog/cwt/django-dynamic-form/ for creating dynamic forms.  It works perfect for creating the forms, but I would like to use some of the inputs with a Textarea widget. This is the code that is working from the tutorial, without any widgets defined:

```
from django import forms
form_config = {'title':'CharField', 'email':'EmailField', 'active':'BooleanField'}
dynamic_form = forms.Form()
for key in form_config.keys():
    dynamic_form.fields.insert(-1, key, getattr(forms, form_config.get(key))())
print dynamic_form.as_table()
```

I tried just adding the widget to the form_config:

```
form_config = {'title':'CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)'}
```

But that gives me a "module object has no attribute" error.  Is there a way to add the widget to the dynamic form?